# launchd error "Could not find and/or execute program specified by service"

Tags: terminal, launchd

I am trying to get a script to run from launchd at regular intervals. The service loads but does not run the script.

The script itself is a very simple test script as follows:

```
echo "Hello World!" >> /Users/rhiannon/Library/Application\ Support/Script\ Testing/test.txt
```

The script is saved as `/Users/rhiannon/Library/Application\ Support/Script\ Testing/test-launchd.sh` (with permissions `rwxr-xr-x`) and happily runs from the command line.

I have a plist file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>uk.co.myco.timedshelltests</string>
        <key>Program</key> 
        <string>/Users/rhiannon/Library/Application\ Support/Script\ Testing/test-launchd.sh</string> 
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>60</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The plist file is saved as `/Users/rhiannon/Library/LaunchAgents/uk.co.myco.timedshelltests.plist` with permissions `rw-r--r--`.

I load the service using

```
launchctl load uk.co.myco.timedshelltests.plist
```

With logging set with `sudo launchctl log level debug`, I see the following error in the system log:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (uk.co.myco.timedshelltests[13505]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 2: No such file or directory: /Users/rhiannon/Library/Application\ Support/Script\ Testing/test-launchd.sh
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (uk.co.myco.timedshelltests[13505]): Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (uk.co.myco.timedshelltests[13505]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
```

I'm pretty certain the permissions are correct, and I know the path is correct. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried sending the "Hello World" string to some other location than `/Library/Application\ Support/Script\ Testing`, perhaps to the Desktop?

Comment: Also, you may need to explicitly put `#!/bin/sh` as the first line of the script. `launchd` doesn't know which shell to use until you tell it which one!

Comment: Note: the escape character,`\\`, shows in the error message. Remove them from the Program key string -in other words leave the spaces unquoted.

Comment: @IconDaemon I do have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script; just omitted it from the above for brevity.

Comment: @fd0 that fixed it, thanks! If you make that comment an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launchd does not perform word splitting. Remove the escape characters `\` from the following line-

```
<string>/Users/rhiannon/Library/Application\ Support/Script\ Testing/test-launchd.sh</string>
```